# How to disable HTTP/2 forwarding on a puma web server running ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, http2, puma, http-1.1

We are currently using AWS CLB so it is not possible to directly configure it for HTTP/2. However a CLB forwards requests as they are received so if the requests are not restricted to HTTP/1.1 (for example) then it would also forward HTTP/2 requests ?
I am looking for similar instructions as [this for apache server](https://forum.directadmin.com/threads/disable-http-2-for-a-specific-domain.62691/) to disable HTTP/2 forwarding on a PUMA web server running a Ruby on Rails application.

I have not tried anything yet as the puma configuration seems to be the only way to restrict the requests to HTTP/1.1